# Puyo Puyo optimal strategies?

Tags: puyo-puyo-tetris, puyo-puyo

In *Puyo Puyo Tetris*, I have plenty of experience with Tetris and how to effectively play.  However, my experience with Puyo Puyo is far more limited, so I'm struggling to get 3 stars in the campaign or win in multiplayer.

I understand the basics of the mechanics, but I need help with strategies.  How should I layout the Puyos on the board to enable larger combos?  How should they be dropped so they're effective on a longer term than just throwing 4 of the same color together one group at a time?

Answer (score 1):

While Tetris is rather straightforward, chaining in Puyo Puyo basically requires practice. You may need to *visualize* how Puyos will fall.

To answer your question, one way to chain is to follow a pattern. A pattern is a specific way of arranging Puyos to cause chain reactions. One such pattern is called the [Stairs](http://puyonexus.com/wiki/Stairs). Most beginner players begin with this pattern.

As you continually play, you may notice that patterns may become static. On the good side, by understanding chaining, you can eventually vary your setups to your liking or strategy.

[This](http://puyonexus.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1865/) forum has a guide in helping people to chain. Good luck!